# Magento 1.9 Caching Skin Files (CSS and JS)

Tags: magento-1.9, cache

Is there anyway to force client side cache.  We would like customers to receive the latest updates made to CSS and JS files without them having to hard cache or clear their browser cache.

We have tried flushing all cache options in the administrative backend udner system -> cache management

We have tried merging the CSS and JS files under system -> advanced -> developer -> CSS/JS settings

We have tried deleting these merge files in media/css_secure in combination with merging and un merging the files as outlined above.

Please advise best practice for releasing the updated files for Magento 1.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way to guarantee users receive the latest CSS/JS files is to change the file name using versioning.

There are modules that can automatically add version tags or timestamps to CSS/JS files.

https://github.com/mklooss/Loewenstark_Head
https://github.com/AOEpeople/Aoe_JsCssTstamp